# What is wrong with this code for glowing LEDs using IR sensor for AVR?

Tags: c, embedded

```
/*This code takes in inputs from IR sensors connected on PA0 and PA1 
and glows LEDs connected on PB0 and PB1*/

#include <avr/io.h>

int main()
{
        DDRA=0x00; // PORTA (PA0 and PA1) will act as input

        DDRB=0x03; //The last two pins PBO and PB1 will act as output.

        int x=0x03 & PINA; //Initially when PINA=0, x=0

        if (x==0x00)
        {
            PORTB=0x00;
        }

        else if (x==0x01) 
// If input is given to PA0 then PINA=0x01 and x=0x01
        {
            PORTB=0x01;
        }

        else if (x==0x02) 
// If input is given to PA1 then PINA=0x02 and x=0x02
        {
            PORTB=0x02;
        }

        else if(x==0x03) 
// If input is given to PA0 and PA1 then PINA=0x03 and x=0x03
        {
            PORTB=0x03;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Returning from main in embedded code for the AVR platform is almost always a bad idea. It will jump back to somewhere else in the code, check the generated assembly output to figure out exactly where, if you want a loop you should just use a proper main loop and not rely on the side effects of the return for performing the main loop.

Comment: Also it would help a lot in a post like this to explain what happens vs what you expected to happen. What exactly is going wrong here?

Comment: If you doesn't use a loop the main is executed only one time. The if should be better as `if ( x&3 == valore )`.

Comment: It will return to the reset ISR and then the program will crash & burn from there.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to have a program that runs continuously is that below. This solution contains some logic adjustments to your code. The logic adjustments allow the code to don't modify all the bits of the port B, in this way the code modifies only the bits 0 and 1 of the port. That allows to use the other bits for other purposes.

```
#include <avr/io.h>

void main()
{
    DDRA=0x00; // PORTA (PA0 and PA1) will act as input
    DDRB=0x03; //The last two pins PBO and PB1 will act as output.

    int x;

    PORTB=0;
    PORTA=0;

    for( ;; ) {
        x=0x03 & PINA; //Initially when PINA=0, x=0

        if (x==0x00)
        {
            PORTB&=(~3);
        }

        else if (x==0x01) 
    // If input is given to PA0 then PINA=0x01 and x=0x01
        {
            PORTB&=(~2);
            PORTB|=0x01;
        }

        else if (x==0x02) 
    // If input is given to PA1 then PINA=0x02 and x=0x02
        {
            PORTB&=(~1);
            PORTB|=0x02;
        }

        else`enter code here` if(x==0x03) 
    // If input is given to PA0 and PA1 then PINA=0x03 and x=0x03
        {
            PORTB|=0x03;
        }

    // Here you may insert a delay
    //delay(50);
    }
}
```

I think a good solution might be the following code:

```
#include <avr/io.h>

void main()
{
    DDRA=0x00; // PORTA (PA0 and PA1) will act as input
    DDRB=0x03; //The last two pins PBO and PB1 will act as output.

    PORTB=0;
    PORTA=0;

    for( ;; ) {
        PORTB &=(~3);
        PORTB |= (PORTA & 3);   

    // Here you may insert a delay
    //  delay(50);
    }
}
```